# (How) does obscuring mist affect the caster inside it?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, combat, rogue

One of my players' characters can use his armor to cast *obscuring mist* in the square where he is.

I'm pretty sure what happens to the enemy that wants to attack him while he stays in the fog, but I'm not sure what happens to him.

He is a rogue that uses a bow to fight: while he is inside his fog, can he target enemies with his bow without any penalties?

What happens if he moves away, and an ally goes inside the fog?

EDIT: Thanks for you answers. I have checked the name and yes is the Mithralmist armor. I don't have the manuals right now, I must investigate more on it and understan if Obscuring Mist is a prerequirements or not

EDIT2: Ok as someone of you says, with the Mithralmist armor the fog doesn't effect the vision of who wear it. So the rogue not only can see without any problem, but have concealment (20% melee, 50% ranged) and can do sneak attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of *mithralmist shirt* is somewhat vague. It not necessarily creates a fog similar to that of Obscuring Mist spell (item's prerequisite to be created), but 'billowing silver mist' it creates still lacks some info to be clear enough as a separate standalone effect.

As written it neither doesn't interfere with your attacks when you shoot from the space filled with it, nor doesn't interfere with your attacks when you leave that space. Also, as written, it grants concealment only to you (sireously, that may be the reason why it doesn't interfere with your vision with no caveats). Those assumptions are questionable while possible. In this case your rogue may shoot freely. But what happens to ranged attacks of those entering his bank of mist is mostly left on DM's mercy.

Another way to interpreate given item is to assume it creates a bank of fog similar to that of it's prerequisite spell. That bank just happens to be only as large as your space is and is in that space when you activate *the shirt*. That way whole discriptive text stays largely true, but we know what to do with cases not touched by it.

If we go this way, either rogue or anyone entering the fog may fire their bows with no hindrances. Obscuring Mist confers concealment depending on the distance between<sup>1</sup> creatures in squares containing the fog. You may treat that as if armor owner was standing on the border of regular Obscuring Mist's effect. As your rogue (or any creature for that matter) stands right next to the border<sup>2</sup> of a clouded area there actually are no squares of fog between her and her target. So her target gains no concealment.

---

1. <sup>For a creature to see into a square that creature's line of sight must be traced into that squere. So a target's squere also counts as part of a distance.</sup>
2. <sup>If your rogue is larger than medium, things may got more complicated. As there will be more than one square to enter, entering creature may position itself in a way it isn't adjacent to the border with respect to it's target. Not to mention, if armor owner himself moves, he may do the same.</sup>

Comment: @GiordiX I hope I'll be able to edit this to reffer updated question in a day or two.

Comment: I have also edit my question, I'm not sure what answer I must check as correct because all of you have reason...

Comment: @GiordiX That's what votes are generally for. You aren't of course obliged to always accept the highest-rated answer as well as you aren't obliged to accept any at all. Still, mechanic of this site is geared towards bringing the most high-quality answer to the top.

Comment: @GiordiX I've edited my answer for it to match your edits. Sorry it took so long. You probably should check if it is suitable as accepted answer now (previous version is available by clicking 'edited [date]' line if you for some reason need it).

Comment: @GiordiX Also, while it may be out of the scope of this question, I should point out, that rogue would get 20% concealment vs either melee or ranged attacks not 20% and 50% respectively. If it would be better, I may incorporate this into an answer.

Comment: Not clear for me, wy he get only the 20%?

Comment: @GiordiX In short, because mithralmist shirt says so. There is no adjustment for distance mentioned, it just grants concealment (default value is 20%). If it works off of a spell, enemy's line of sight passes through a single square (the one rogue stands in) of the effect. Single fogged square = 5 feet away (per the spell) = concealment. More squares filled with fog = further away (per the spell) = total concealment. I don't think clear squares (those not included in the spell's or item's area of effect) add to a concealment level.

Comment: Mmm, well I don't have manuals now but I thought that when the rogue actived the armor ability, a fog appears around him, so all the square around him grants 20% concealment for melee attacks and 50% for ranged. The manuals says that the fog appears "in the space you are", this means on the same (and only) square the rogue is (only 5 feet)? If yes, if he he move a step backward in such a way he have the fog in front of him, he gets the total concealment in front direction?

Comment: @GiordiX If you are medium yes, it means only 5 feet of fog. And no, I don't think it will grant more concealment from a distance.

Answer (score 9):

Unless a spell says otherwise, they affect everyone in their area. That includes the rogue as well as any of the rogue’s allies. The *Complete Adventurer* ninja has a variant in an issue of *Dragon* magazine that even boasts as its primary class feature an ability to use *obscuring mist* without affecting the ninja himself. This replaces the ninja’s usual invisibility, to give you an idea of how potent that is. It is definitely not an automatic part of the spell.

As such, *obscuring mist* is generally seen as an emergency escape option, a way to prevent attacks against you and allow you to flee. It can be awkwardly used for surprise melee attacks, but the miss chance is pretty high so that isn’t recommended.

The rogue could also blind-fire his bow through the mist. If he picks the right square, he has a 50% chance of missing outright (before he even gets to compare his attack roll against the target’s AC), but since the target has concealment from him, he cannot use precision damage—like sneak attack—on that target.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually loosely familiar with the armor you are talking about (if it's homebrew, there is an actual RAW version, just so you know). I don't recall the name off the top of my head (that said, I'll probably find it in the next few days anyway).

Anyhow, to the point of the matter -- if this is the armor I think it is (and I only know one that does this), then RAW I believe it does state he is immune to his own armor's ability.

Allies, however, are not covered in that statement.

Please note that I'll probably be nagged by this question, so this answer will likely be edited once I find the reference.

EDIT: Yep. Found the armor -- it's called Mithralmist Armor. Tenative citation is MIC, but I'll have to dig further to check this.

Comment: Sooo, just noting I'll be editing this with the fact that it is Mithralmist armor. Can't find the page citation, but I THINK it's from MIC.

Comment: Looks like *Magic Item Compendium* page 20, and yeah, that looks like a likely candidate for what prompted this question. Make sure in your answer to explain about how the *mithralmist shirt* **doesn’t** use *obscuring mist* and how it’s a unique effect. Pointing out that just having *obscuring mist* as a requirement (which it does) doesn’t mean its effect has anything to do with *obscuring mist* is a good idea. And I think ultimately the answer is that *Magic Item Compendium* **is** being a bit sparse here, and leaves some questions as to how it works.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the pointers. I found an online reference, so I didn't have the full info. Don't have my books available to check RN, I'll read up/edit tomorrow.